# About query written in Domain Relational Calculus

Tags: database, domain-calculus

I am trying to learn Domain relational calculus. Considering the below relations and queries, why can't we write for`{<c>|< b, l, c, a> ∈ borrow ∧ a>1200}` the second question? I have a feeling that it has something to do with whether the query is safe, but how come the answer for question one works? I don't know what exactly is wrong. Could you please help to explain? Many thanks! 
[image]
[image]
Source from http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter3/node18.html#SECTION00142000000000000000
and the relations it refers to is here http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter3/node8.html#SECTION00121000000000000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, that the definition of query in Domain Relational Calculus

```
{<x1, ..., xn> | P(<x1, ..., xn>)}
```

says that the variables `x1, ..., xn` that appear to the left of ‘|’ must be
the only free variables in the formula `p(...)`. In your example, variables `b,l,a` are not bound and remain free. In the correct answer, the existence quantifier binds them.

Comment: Thank you! So by using the "Exist" notation, "b,l,a" are bounded?

Comment: Yes, Exist (as well as All) bind its variables